# Page A to page B - Connect the pages to be recognized as logged in

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I have created some access controlled pages which can be viewed only after logged in. I had to create another page which holds a form where the user is going to fill the details and submit it. But am not able to connect page A to page B so that the user is still logged in.

I try to add the codes that I used in the access controlled pages to the Page B which has a form. But then the page shows internal error 500.

The code that I am using on the access controlled pages is

```
<?PHP
require_once("./include/membersite_config.php");

if(!$fgmembersite->CheckLogin())
{
    $fgmembersite->RedirectToURL("login.php");
    exit;
}
?>
```

When I try to use the same for the Page B which has a form for submission, it doesn't work.

Something is conflicting.

Here is the code on the Page B

```
<?PHP

require_once("./separate/include/fgcontactformuser.php");
require_once("./separate/include/captcha-creator.php");

$formproc = new FGContactForm();
$captcha = new FGCaptchaCreator('scaptcha');

$formproc->EnableCaptcha($captcha);

$formproc->AddRecipient('mail.com'); //<<---Put your email address here

$formproc->SetFormRandomKey('H04uLRJh4CY5sR4');

if(isset($_POST['submitted']))
{
   if($formproc->ProcessForm())
   {
        $formproc->RedirectToURL("PageB.php");
   }
}

?>
```

Why is there a conflict and why it doesn't work?

Comment: add the code:  ini_set("display_errors",1);  to the page which is giving you the error.

Comment: why don't you use http cookies? They are easy to set with php. Also, I second what Mike B said. Please accept more answers to your questions because it will make others more willing to answer your new questions.

Comment: Check your server logs to see what caused the 500 error.

Comment: I would be glad if someone could demonstrate the code to remove the error. I want to pass the user to the PageB and still show him as logged in.

Comment: There might be some php clash for sure. Let me try what @PhilCross suggested.

Comment: The 500 server internal error is thrown by the web server. Maybe you can find a clue.